# BIRT scripted data source error

Tags: datasource, birt

Thanks for the information on creating the .jars for using scripted data sources. I followed the directions but  I get this error:

> JavaPackage com.actuate.json.JSONParser is not a function, it is an object

When I try to run the report. Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm using BDPro Actuate 11SP3.

Comment: What information?  Are you referening to a question/answer on SO?  if so which one?

Comment: Are you 100% sure there are no (syntax) errors in your data source? (That's one of the things that can lead to this error, although it has nothing to do with the package.)

Answer (score -1):

To late but had the same issue. Thats because the class does not exist.

Use this.

https://github.com/mcasperson/birt-jsonparser/blob/master/src/main/java/com/actuate/json/JSONParser.java